# Use Vlans on different subnets

Tags: vlan, subnet

Why we use vlans in the different subnets, the subnets are independent so why??

I know it is a beginner question  help me please

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because VLANs provide layer-2 segregation while subnetting is layer-3.

Two different subnets on the same VLAN (broadcast domain) will still see all the broadcast frames for each.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean to prevent broadcast from other subnets?

Comment: No, I'm talking about broadcast frames in layer-2 and not broadcast packets in layer-3. Two different layer-3 subnets will both see all the broadcast frames if they're in the same VLAN because they share layer-2.